# OneNote API with OneNote in SharePoint document library

Tags: onenote, onenote-api

Is there a way in the OneNote API (or Graph API) to interact with a OneNote document stored in a SharePoint document library somewhere?
Not the site notebook.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OneNote API supports site-hosted notebooks. More details are in this blog post.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/onenotedev/2015/06/11/and-sharepoint-makes-three/

I'm not sure what you mean by SharePoint document library - isn't it the same as a SharePoint site?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken that is the site's notebook. Not a notebook that is stored in some doc lib somewhere.

Comment: I meant the blog post is about the site's notebook. Not a library.

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint document libraries are contained inside of a SharePoint site. The blog talks about working with any OneNote notebook in any document library on a SharePoint site. You need to know which site you want to work with first (either by URL or ids). Then you can query for notebooks on the site etc.

Comment: new day, new eyes.  You are quite right, my apologies.